# Angular / Typescript convert Method with Promise to Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

I have the method which works as intended:

```
getdata(): Promise<any> {
    let query = `SELECT * FROM table`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.query(query, (error, rows) => {
        if(error) reject(error);
        resolve(rows);
      });
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myservice.getdata().then(result => {
      this.data = result;
    })
}
```

I'm using Angular 9 / Electron

How can I change this to work as an Observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to return a RxJS `Subject` observable.

```js
completed$ = new Subject<any>();

getdata(): Observable<any> {
  const result = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  const query = `SELECT * FROM table`;
  this.db.query(query, (error, rows) => {
    error ? result.error(error) : result.next(rows);
  });
  return result.asObservable();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.getdata().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.completed$)
  ).subscribe(
    rows => {
      if (rows) {          // <-- check if response is valid
        this.data = rows;
      } 
    },
    error => { }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.completed$.next();
  this.completed$.complete();
}
```

Comment: there are a couple subtle bugs in this method. 1. if the consumer doesn't subscribe right away, `next` might be called before the consumer subscribes and they'll miss the value, you could somewhat fix this with a `ReplaySubject` but it still breaks the observable expectation that things won't execute until subscribed 2. something like a db query would be expected to complete on it's own without the need to manually complete or unsubscribe, this could be fixed with an operator or calling `complete` on the subject.

Comment: What's this.completed$ ? Do I just defined it in the component?

Comment: @joe2020wow: Unclosed subscriptions may lead to potential memory leaks. Using RxJS `takeUntil()` operator is one of the way to make sure we close the subscription. `completed$` may be a Subject observable that is completed in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Same issues as others. I need to run it twice to get the data: test() {
    this.myservice.getdata().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.completed$)
    ).subscribe(
      rows => { this.data = rows },
      error => { }
    );
  }

Comment: @joe2020wow: I don't understand what you mean by run it twice. In the question you were subscribing in the `ngOnInit()` hook, so you don't have to call any other functions.

Comment: I get no data when I have it ngOnInit, so I tried calling it as a method on a button click. I realized I get no data until I call it twice

Comment: @joe2020wow: I've replace the `Subject` with a `BehaviorSubject` with default value `null`. The difference b/n them is that ``BehaviorSubject` could hold a value and emit it immediately upon subscription. So we need to check if value is valid before assigning it. Try again in `ngOnInit()` and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

you can just wrap any promise in `from` to convert it to an observable:

```
getdata(): Observable<any> {
    let query = `SELECT * FROM table`;
    return from(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.query(query, (error, rows) => {
        if(error) reject(error);
        resolve(rows);
      });
    }));
}
```

or you can skip the promise and go ahead and create an observable directly:

```
getdata(): Observable<any> {
    let query = `SELECT * FROM table`;
    return new Observable((obs) => {
      this.db.query(query, (error, rows) => {
        if (error) {
          obs.error(error);
        } else {
          obs.next(rows);
          obs.complete();
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can't use this one as for some reason I need to run this twice to get the data: this.myservice.getdata().subscribe(data => {
      this.queryResult = data;
    });

Comment: not sure what you mean by you "need to run this twice" ... both of these methods will work more or less the same but i'd recommend the second in this particular case. though `bindNodeCallback` is a good option too that i forgot, it's essentially a convenience wrapper around the second method

Comment: I tried the second one calling it from a button click. The data doesn't appear until my second click

Comment: that sounds like a change detection problem more than an observable problem.  The promise triggering might've been masking some other issue you have going on. if you add logging in the subscribe handler, are you seeing the data on the first click?

Comment: that's correct ... I tried console.log and the data came out on the first click but not on the component view until the second click

Comment: Yea. You have a bug in your change detection then. Any observable method will have the same outcome. The promise was masking it. You should try to fix whatever is going on there as it could mean you have deeper issues. Are you using on push detection? Or running outside of ngZone or using jquery or something?

Comment: Not at all.... Just a service and a component and running on electron..I get no errors at all :o/

Comment: Don’t know. Can’t diagnose a change detection issue without seeing all the relevant code and preferably getting a reproduction of the issue. You can hack around it using ChangeDetectorRef from angular core, but i don’t recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a function with a callback whose first parameter is `error` ("Node.js-style callback") to Observable is best done with `bindNodeCallback`:

```
getdata(): Observable<any> {
  const query = `SELECT * FROM table`;
  return bindNodeCallback(this.db.query)(query)
}

// subscribing:
ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.getdata().subscribe(result => {
    this.data = result;
  });
}
```

[Reference](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindNodeCallback)

Comment: I get Error: Cannot find name 'bindNodeCallback'

Answer (score 1):

The most proper way is to use [`bindNodeCallback`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindNodeCallback)

```
getdata(): Promise<any> {
  return bindNodeCallback(this.db.query)(`SELECT * FROM table`);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.getdata().subscribe(result => {
    this.data = result;
  });
}
```